# 3 columns, center column fixed, sides fill parents

Tags: css

How can I make B be a fixed 800px size while A and C fill the space, so they are all together touching? http://jsfiddle.net/8ufuV/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest method is to use `display: table-cell`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/47d4f/

That solves your problem, and also gives you [equal height columns](http://jsfiddle.net/47d4f/1/) when the content is different in each column - something that isn't otherwise *simple* to obtain.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: Little note: IE7 and earlier don't support table-cell and IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE.

Comment: oops sorry I meant to give you the solution I mixed up the posts

Comment: it works how I want it except for one thing, I need the C column to be position:fixed to stay on the top, when I do that it doesn't fill the space to the right, there's a gap to the right, how could I fix this?

Comment: That's difficult to do. I'll have a think. Is using JavaScript/jQuery an option?

Comment: This continued here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711576/break-long-word-in-a-div-when-word-wrapbreak-word-fails

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it up for you http://jsfiddle.net/8ufuV/17/
You need to float all the elements left; and then specific a width (don't forget about padding/margins when doing so). On an element you want to appear below them add `clear:left;` to it.

Good luck

Comment: How doesn't it work? Floating 3 elements with a set width is how every single css grid works.

Comment: How does this even answer the question? :S "How can make [the central one] be a fixed 800px size" - in your demo, the central `div` is set to `80%`.

Comment: the question was to set the middle content div to a fixed width, yours isn't fixed. Also the third column breaks into the next row when the browser window gets smaller.

Comment: Thats because jsfiddle is not 800 pixels wide. I've set it to examples of what he could use.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

<div id="leftblock">a</div>

<div id="contentblock">b</div>

<div id="rightblock">c</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
  display:table;
  width:100%
}

div {
  display: table-cell
}

#leftblock{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  voice-family: "\"}\"";
  voice-family:inherit;
}

#contentblock{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
}


#rightblock{
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  voice-family: "\"}\"";
  voice-family:inherit;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `voice-family:` properties?

Comment: It's the original CSS file posted in jsfiddle by **madprops**. I have not made any chanages in that. It will work without that also.

Comment: OK; so your answer is "use `display: table-cell`, then? You should explain the answer in addition to the code, so it's more clear what you have done to make it work.