# 2 column div layout: right column fixed width, left fluid, height relative to eachother

Tags: css, html, fixed, fluid

I want a layout with two columns, two divs, where the left one has fluid width and the right one has fixed width. So far so good - see jsfiddle below - however, the height of the right column must be in relation to the height of the left column. So that if I have some content in the fluid column and would resize the browser window, thereby increasing or decreasing the height of the left column, the right one should follow and getting the same height.

What I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/vnUdc/2/

Edit: Resolved, see comment below

Comment: Do you need to support IE7? If not, you can use `display: table-cell`. [Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708816/3-columns-center-column-fixed-sides-fill-parents/6708947#6708947)

Comment: @thirtydot thanks alot, that worked like a charm! Do not need IE7 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got an answer to my question from @thirtydot (see comment above):

> Do you need to support IE7? If not, you can use display: table-cell

Comment: Tried to find a way to set comment as accepted answer but couldn't seem to find a good way. Please correct me if it was wrong to post an answer myself like this.

Comment: where do u add the table-cell property?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the ol' two column layout. Unless you want to resort to JavaScript to track the height of one column to adjust the other, you're not going to be able to do it in the way you expect. Using height="100%" usually doesn't work in these situations, either.

What you *can* do is something like the old [Faux Column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique. The div's don't resize, but you have a background image on the parent element that tiles vertically, giving the illusion of equal columns. Old school, yes, but effective.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work since I need the two columns to be of the same height. The reason is that I need to position a button in the middle (vertically) of the right column.

Comment: ahh - yeah, then faux columns won't work. looks like you got a good idea from thirtydot

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the height of the left `div`, then set the right `div` to this height.

To get height of the left div:

```
var divHeight = document.getElementById('left').offsetHeight;
```

To set height of right div:

```
document.getElementById('right').style.height = divHeight+'px';
```

[Your JSFiddle example fixed.](http://jsfiddle.net/bz4fu/)

Comment: Thanks for that input, but I need to make it work without Javascript. Thirtydot provided a solution though, see above.