# CSS three column resize issue

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I have a web layout that currently looks like this:

[image]

The black column (the middle column) has a fixed width (728px). This is the CSS for it:

```
width: 728px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Then, I have the two red bars on opposite sides of the screen. For instance, the CSS of the bar on the left side is:

```
background: red;
height: 100%;
float: left;
width: 300px;
```

...and on the right:

```
background: red;
height: 100%;
float: right;
width: 300px;
```

However, I want to make it so that the red bars adjust their width AUTOMATICALLY according to the screen size. However, at the same time, I want it to NOT affect the middle black bar (728px).

So in other words, I want it so that the red bars go right up against the middle black bar while not affecting it's size (no matter what the screen size is).

As seen in my image, this is not working out as the red bars are NOT going against the edge of the margin. I have already tried things such as width auto, initial, and inherit. Nothing is working.

**Edit:**

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-bar">
    </div>
    <div id="right-bar">
    </div>
    <div id="middle-column">
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for container is just the following:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 columns, center column fixed, sides fill parents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708816/3-columns-center-column-fixed-sides-fill-parents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `calc()` on both the right and left bars:

```
#right-bar {
    width: calc(50% - 364px);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K8qba/

Comment: Yes, however, I'm going to have content in those two sidebars.

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML and full CSS in a fiddle?